Remove "New Item" button/action from the proposed column in Azure DevOps
I want this button removed/disabled/not available

Basically, it causes people to create work items that aren't categorized correctly, just with the default area, and then they go missing. We have processes to catch this and fix it, but not having that area also messes with a bunch of other things.
I tried to see if there was some way to disable saving a work item with a default area, but I found nothing.
I tried to find a way to kill this action, but again I found nothing.

Which page are you seeing that on? Are you using hosted or deployed? Which project template are you using (CMMI, Agile etc.)?

@spikey_richie this is on the board for features. Hosted. CMMI
